# C# Select all Images from SQL table into all pictureboxes

Tags: c#, image, populate

I want to use code from SQL: SELECT * FROM USERS
this table includes images and I want to apply all the images against each user.
I am using user control and each user control has user details, Name, Surname and image.

I was trying to populate images from my table but I get same image in all usercontrol pictureboxes.

```
    private void populateItems()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
            {
                //Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                //Loop and add SelectUser:Usercontrol to FloyLayoutPanel.
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    SelectContacts contact = new SelectContacts();
                    contact.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                    contact.LastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
                    contact.Title = row["Title"].ToString();

                    byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                    contact.PublicProfilePic = Image.FromStream(ms);

                    flowUsers.Controls.Add(contact);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It supposed to show me different picture that are related to user.
But instead I get first available image in all pictureboxes.

How can I populate individual images against individual user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the for-each loop rather than taking the corresponding row(user) image, you are fetching the first user's image for all the rest. 
In each iteration take the `row["image"]` NOT `dt.Rows[0]["Image"]`.

For the null value checking, you can use the following classic way

```
object value = row["Image"];
    if (value == DBNull.Value)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }
```

or use a ternary operator.

```
int? myValue = (Convert.IsDBNull(row["column"]) ? null : (int?) Convert.ToInt32(row["column"]));
```

Comment: If you found its worked make my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You're just collecting the first image here:

`byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];`

change that line of code to

`byte[] img = (byte[])row["Image"];`

and there are many ways to avoid null errors:

```
// Using "as" keyword is the best practice only
// in case you are doing null check after the cast
byte[] img = row["Image"] as byte[];
// OR the following will either give you the image or an empty byte array.
byte[] img = row["Image"] as byte[] ?? new byte[];
```

But always remember to check for nulls so you don't hit any errors.

Here's how the full code should look:

```
private void populateItems()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Users";
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
        {
            //Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            //Loop and add SelectUser:Usercontrol to FloyLayoutPanel.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                SelectContacts contact = new SelectContacts();
                contact.FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                contact.LastName = row["LastName"].ToString();
                contact.Title = row["Title"].ToString();

                byte[] img = row["Image"] as byte[];

                if(img != null && img.length > 0)
                {
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                    contact.PublicProfilePic = Image.FromStream(ms);
                }

                flowUsers.Controls.Add(contact);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, but how can I allow nulls? In SQL I allow nulls but here in application I get this. Unable to cast object of type system.dbnull to type system.byte[]

Comment: Updated for you.

Comment: Was the question mark an accident? It doesn't work with it and if I take it off, I get this. "System.ArgumentNullException: Buffer cannot be null. Parameter name: buffer."

Comment: What .net framework are you using? You should be able to just use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The `0` in the below line is the culprit.

```
byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];
```

use

```
byte[] img = (byte[])row["Image"];
```

Comment: Could you please show me how? I am not so good at images in C#

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
dt.Rows[0]["Image"]
```

Use:

```
row["Image"]
```

At the moment you are only accessing the image from the first row in your results. The change above will give it to you for each row.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are getting the first row from the rows object here

```
byte[] img = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Image"];
```

Since you allow null in database, try something like this,

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(row["Image"])) { 
   byte[] img = (byte[])row["Image"];                     
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
   contact.PublicProfilePic = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: Still same error. Unable cast object of type. System.DBNull. to Type System.Byte[]
And it comes up in this stage: byte[] img = (byte[])row["Image"];

Comment: Try to add !Convert.IsDBNull(row["Image"]) in the if-statment instead, I have edited the code for you.